# Bar chart in High chart for indication of value with two colors in each bar where one color is always kept fixed

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

I am working on a project and I would like to use bar chart(HighChart) to indicate values. I prefer to use bar chart of this kind-
[bar chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftcm5.png)

If any one have worked on this type of bar chart or have any idea of how to implement it, please share. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set axis min max and then create an additional series which will complete the first series data to the axis max. For the additional, dummy series set options like `enableMouseTracking` or `showInLegend` to false so it wont inteact with the user.

```
    yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 700
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      grouping: false,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },

  series: [{
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    linkedTo: 1,
    data: [{
      y: 700,
      color: 'rgba(66, 134, 244, 0.5)'
    }, {
      y: 700,
      color: 'rgba(206, 49, 28, 0.5)'
    }]
    }, {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      style: {
        fontSize: '20px',
        textOutline: null
      }
    },
    data: [{
      y: 107,
      color: 'rgba(66, 134, 244, 1)'
    }, {
      y: 31,
      color: 'rgba(206, 49, 28, 1)'
    }]
  }]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/sL5bpep3/

[image: column]

Comment: @moganfree..Thank you so much for your response and it really helps.